# how to add highcharts in Datatables child row , from google sheets?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, google-sheets, datatables

how to add highcharts in datatables child rows?

I have datatables + sheets and i want add highcharts in child rows

1. datatables parent row ( google )
2. highcharts  child row (microsoft)
3. datatables parent row ( google )
4. highcharts  child row (microsoft)

please help me 
I don't know js and I'm not programmer

full code

```
http:// codepen.io/intprotest/pen/eXbKMj?editors=1010
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8kjy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add Highcharts source code:

`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

Next, you have to create a HTML container for a chart, for example:

```
function format(title) {
    return '<div class="slider" name>' +
        '<table class=table  table hover     border="0"     class="details-table">' +
        ... +

        '<div id="chart' + title[14] + '"></div>' +
        '</div>'
}
```

And finally, you can create a chart in `click` event function:

```
        $('#selection-datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
            ...
            else {
                ...
                createChart('chart' + row.data()[14], row.data().slice(16));
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
            }
        });


    });

function createChart(container, data) {

    Highcharts.chart(container, {
        series: [{
            data: (function() {
                data.forEach(function(el, i) {
                    data[i] = Number(el);
                });

                return data;
            })()
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        }
    })
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6g02a1uz/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

Comment: i have another datatables+Charts and data is Json + timestamp and i want change  json +timestamp format and you can help me ?  i want data from google sheets or i want  change timestamp date format and i want standard date foramt + Json/csv ------   full code https://codepen.io/intprotest/pen/YeOKBg?editors=1010

Comment: var country_data = 
{"Canada": {"1410048000": 0.417 --- json timestamp format and i want  standard date format -  var country_data = 
{"Canada": {"08/07/2019": 0.417 or "08-07-2019": 0.417

Comment: or i want  full change and data from  google sheets .  Thank you very much !!!  sorry   I'm not programmer :(

Comment: Hi @IntProtest, Could you specify your question? Your example seems to work correctly.

Comment: i want     change json data . i want  data from sheets or csv/json and standard date format , i no want  json+date timestamp format

Comment: @IntProtest  - Your JSON seems to be incorrect: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Comment: hello , you can help me ?  you can code update ? don't work now ( api v3)  
new url and please update code . Thanks !  https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1f8Ji80Qv3PX3mcUbHs5MeVHmTdC1lxBoPu72XInckaA/values/1?alt=json&key=AIzaSyB5FsZ-XKEpJVPSmTbQhJPNMOIPYO8VmhU

Comment: Hi @IntProtest, Please create a new question with `highcharts` tag.